# Populating a listBox from the local PC

Tags: c#, silverlight

I would like to populate my ListBox with whatever items there is in the specific path.

```
string path = @"C:\users\test\desktop";
```

So whatever items there are on my desktop, the listbox should have those items in it.

I tried making the `ListBox1.ItemSource = path` , but all that does is it writes the path to the listbox :(.

Any suggestions or help.

Thanks

Comment: This is very simple have you tried to do a google search .. you want to look at Directory.GetFiles.. from there you want to use the Add method of the ListBox1 Object ... hopefully this will help you to try the coding on your own....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at [this article](http://www.kunal-chowdhury.com/2011/06/silverlight-5-features-local-file.html). Specifically, these sections:

Once you setup your project properties, open the XAML file and add a `Button` called "Read File" and attach a `Click_Event` to it. We will also add a `ListBox`, so that we can display the text content inside it. Here is the code snippet of the same:

```
<UserControl x:Class="FileAccessDemo.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">

    <StackPanel x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="White">
        <Button Width="150" Height="26" Content="Read File" Click="Button_Click"/>
        <ListBox x:Name="lstContent"/>
    </StackPanel>
</UserControl>
```

Now we need to implement the `Click` event logic for the `Button`. To do this, go to the code behind file and write your own logic to read any file present in your system. In our example, we will use the [`System.IO.File`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.aspx) class and read the hosts file. Then we will add the content in our `ListBox`.

Here is the code implementation:

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    string fileContent = File.ReadAllText(@"c:\windows\system32\drivers\etc\hosts");
    lstContent.Items.Add(fileContent);
}
```

Just call the `File.ReadAllText()` method and pass the complete file path as the parameter. This will read the content and store it in a local variable called `fileContent`. Now add the content to our `ListBox`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass a collection of the files at that path to the `ItemsSource` property - the `ListBox` won't read from the path for you. Have a look at [this](http://www.kunal-chowdhury.com/2010/07/file-explorer-using-silverlight-4-com.html) project that aims to create a file explorer in Silverlight. It should give you some hints as to what you need as well as show you how to go about the `ListBox` population step.